# python 3 empty graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem showing data in a graph. The graph frame appears, but no graph is to be seen. Can you please help ?

I made sure that the dimension of the x axis and the data is the same ... I simply cannot find out why I do not get a graph in return.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
 import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm


n = 1000
theta = 0.8

d = np.sqrt(1-theta**2)

def p(x,y):
    "Stochastic kernel for the TAR model"
    return norm().pdf((y-theta*np.abs(x))/d)/d


Z = norm().rvs(n)
X = np.empty(n)

for t in range(n-1):
    X[t+1] = theta*np.abs(X[t])+d*Z[t+1]


n = len(X)
X = X.reshape((n, 1))

ys = np.linspace(-3,3,200)
k = len(ys)
ys = ys.reshape((1,k))

v = p(X,ys)
kernel = np.mean(v, axis=0)    
h = len(kernel)
kernel = kernel.reshape((1,h))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
ax.plot(ys,kernel, 'b-', lw=2,alpha=0.6, label='look ahead estimate')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that through reshaping the two 1-dimensional arrays `ys` and `kernel` to a 1x`k` or 1x`h` array respectively you get 2-dimensional arrays, where the first dimension is 1. The `plot` function apparently only iterates through the first dimension, which is why the plot doesn't show anything. 
I can think of two easy options to fix that:

1. Do not reshape the variables `kernel` and `ys`:

   ```
   # ... continuing your code ...
   ys = np.linspace(-3,3,200)
   k = len(ys)
   #ys = ys.reshape((1,k))

   v = p(X,ys)
   kernel = np.mean(v, axis=0)    
   h = len(kernel)
   #kernel = kernel.reshape((1,h)) 


   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
   ax.plot(ys,kernel, 'b-', lw=2,alpha=0.6, label='look ahead estimate')
   plt.show()
   ```
2. Call your plot function like this:

   ```
   ax.plot(ys[0],kernel[0], 'b-', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='look ahead estimate')
   ```

I hope this solves your problem.

**To understand why you still have to reshape X:**

Let's first understand your function `p(x,y)` in terms of dimensions:

```
def p(x,y):
    "Stochastic kernel for the TAR model"
    """If x is not reshaped, you substract two one-dimensional arrays from each other,
    which have not the same dimensions (dim(x) == 1000, dim(y) == 200 in your case).
    This throws an error.
    If you reshape X before passing to this function, the y array is substracted
    element-wise by each of the values of X, which gives you a matrix with dimension
    dim(x) x dim(y).
    """
    return norm().pdf((y-theta*np.abs(x))/d)/d
```

For illustration what happens here dimension-wise:

```
>>> X = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
>>> Y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> Y-X
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0],
       [-3, -2, -1]])
```

Now we take a look what happens with the matrix returned by `p(x,y)`:

The calculation of the `kernel` with `np.mean(v, axis=0)`, where `v` is the returned matrix from `p(X,ys)`, works such, that `np.mean` iterates over the lines of the matrix `v` and calculates the mean value of each "line vector" in the matrix. This gives you an one dimensional array (dimension of `ys`) which you can plot over `ys`.

Comment: Thank you very much ... It is working now. I did what you suggested, not reshaping kernel and ys. I am actually struggling to understand why I still have to reshape X to get it to work. Do you know ?

Comment: I think I finally figured out what happens in your code, and made an edit to the answer so that I could explain it (hopefully) more understandable than in a comment. I hope it's clear now why you have to reshape X but not ys and kernel :)